# Acceptable Definition for $\sqrt{a}$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Is this an acceptable definition for $\sqrt{a}$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

If $a\geq 0, \sqrt{a} = b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $b\geq 0, b^2 = a$.

I'm proving some theorems involving $\sqrt{a}$, in the context of introductory real analysis.

Comment: How have you defined $b^2$?

Comment: This definition looks fine, except on the first line you write "Is this an acceptable definition for $\sqrt{a}$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$", you probably $a\in\mathbb{R}$ want to be $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq 0\}$. The other point is stylistic. I think that the term "such that" in the second line would work better as an if and only if. I do not recall seeing such that used in that way (although it might be done for all I know).

Comment: Yes, that definition can be decoded, but I think it would be better to use more English words.  For example, you could say "given a real number $a \ge 0$ we define $\sqrt{a}$ to be the unique real number $b \ge 0$ satisfying $b^2=a$."

Comment: @TrevorWilson How have you defined $b^2$?

Comment: @DonLarynx I haven't defined it above, but when I define $b^2$ I define it as $b \times b$ (or $b \cdot b$, depending on how multiplication is written in the context.)  Or I might define $b^n$ by recursion on natural numbers $n$ as follows: $b^0 = 1$, and $b^{n+1} = b^n \cdot b$.

Answer (score -5):

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. $\sqrt{a}$ is the square root of $a$ and is defined as $f(a) = b$ such that $f:a \to a\times a = b$. Notice the product then can never be negative, because $\mathbb{R}$ is reflexive.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this definition.  What is $f$?  Shouldn't $\sqrt{a}$ be the _unique_ something rather than "all" of something?  And what do you mean by "$\mathbb{R}$ is reflexive"?

Comment: Reflexive means $a \tilde R a$

Comment: WHY THE DOWNVOTE?

Comment: Neither downvote was mine, but presumably they happened because your answer doesn't make any sense.  I still don't understand why you are talking about an $f$, and also after your latest edit it seems to say that $\sqrt{a} = a \times a$ rather than the other way around.  Also, I know what it means for a binary relation $R$ to be reflexive, but I still don't know that it means for the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers to be reflexive, or what that would have to do with the question.

Comment: $=$ is the equality relation and implies either direction @TrevorWilson.

Comment: Sorry, my comment about "the other way around" was unclear.  What I meant to say is that, assuming you are using $f(a)$ to denote $\sqrt{a}$ for some reason, it looks like you are saying that "$\sqrt{a} = b$" is equivalent to "$a \times a = b$", which of course is backward:  it should be $b \times b = a$.